# Python - How to call bash commands with pipe?

Tags: python, popen, subprocess

I can run this normally on the command line in Linux:

```
$ tar c my_dir | md5sum
```

But when I try to call it with Python I get an error:

```
>>> subprocess.Popen(['tar','-c','my_dir','|','md5sum'],shell=True)
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x26c0550>
>>> tar: You must specify one of the `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label'  options
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

Comment: Why are you hashing a tar file? Do you mean to be looking for changes in file contents? or verify an externally created tar file?

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306205/file-not-found-error-when-launching-a-subprocess-containing-piped-commands

Comment: @tMC: and how does this comment help with the actual problem and question ???

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to use `subprocess.PIPE`, also, to split the command, you should use `shlex.split()` to prevent strange behaviours in some cases:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from shlex import split
p1 = Popen(split("tar -c mydir"), stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(split("md5sum"), stdin=p1.stdout)
```

But to make an archive and generate its checksum, you should use Python built-in modules `tarfile` and `hashlib` instead of calling shell commands.

Comment: tarfile, and hashlib would be preferable.  But how do I hash a tarfile object?

Comment: @Greg don't hash the tarfile object, open the resulting file like any other file using `open()` and then hash its content.

Comment: Makes sense.  That works but I get a different hash value than from the original command.  Is that to be expected?

Comment: @Greg, this should do the same exact thing as `tar -c mydir | md5sum`. Perhaps you could start a new question, including an interactive terminal session where you run this command, start Python, and run the Python commands, displaying the output.

Comment: Perhaps also mention that you have to call `communicate` on the final `Popen` object, or switch to a modern wrapper like `subprocess.run`. For many cases, simply pass in a string with `shell=True` if you want to use shell features like pipes, variables, redirection, job control, etc. Or as the answer suggests, run as little as possible in a subprocess and replace shell commands with native Python where you can (in which case you can often avoid [the security implications of `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) by removing it).

Answer (score 10):

Ok, I'm not sure why but this seems to work:

```
subprocess.call("tar c my_dir | md5sum",shell=True)
```

Anyone know why the original code doesn't work?

Comment: the pipe | is a character the shell understands to connect command inputs and outputs together. It is not an argument that tar understands, nor a command. You're trying to execute everything as arguments to the tar command, unless you create a subshell.

Comment: The works because the entire command is passed to the *shell* and the *shell* understands the `|`. Popen calls the process and passes in the arguments directly. For Popen this is controlled with `shell=` and passing a string (not a list), IIRC.

Answer (score 4):

What you actually want is to run a shell subprocess with the shell command as a parameter:

```
>>> subprocess.Popen(['sh', '-c', 'echo hi | md5sum'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
('764efa883dda1e11db47671c4a3bbd9e  -\n', None)
```

Comment: Incidentally, `shell=True` [does something similar.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4d2957c1b9a915f76da418e89bf9b5add141ca3e/Lib/subprocess.py#L1708)

Comment: It's just silly to not use `shell=True` here.

Answer (score 2):

i would try your on python v**3.8.10** :

```
import subprocess
proc1 = subprocess.run(['tar c my_dir'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
proc2 = subprocess.run(['md5sum'], input=proc1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
print(proc2.stdout.decode())
```

key points (like outline in my solution on related https://stackoverflow.com/a/68323133/12361522):

- `subprocess.run()`
- no splits of bash command and parameters, i.e. `['tar c my_dir']`or `["tar c my_dir"]`
- `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` for all processes
- `input=proc1.stdout` chain of output of previous one into input of the next one
- enable shell `shell=True`

Comment: This is basically just a restatement of the accepted answer. The use of `run` over `Popen` is a good idea when you can, of course (back when the accepted answer was written, `run` didn't exist).

Comment: thanks for posting this example, i needed to have `grep` in my command string, which did weird stuff when being supplied to `split`.

Comment: I would prefer this over the accepted answer due to using `run` instead of `shlex`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
>>> import hashlib
>>> proc = Popen(['tar','-c','/etc/hosts'], stdout=PIPE)
>>> stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
>>> hashlib.md5(stdout).hexdigest()
'a13061c76e2c9366282412f455460889'
>>>
```