# subprocess: FileNotFound

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, command

Could someone explain this error to me:

```
>>> def j():
...     import subprocess
...     print(subprocess.Popen(['command', '-v', 'nmcli'],     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE))
... 
>>> j()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 3, in j
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1457, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'command'
```

I tried as a string as a list, it does not change anything.

Comment: For the somewhat more common case of FileNotFoundErrors for commands which are not shell builtins, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306205/file-not-found-error-when-launching-a-subprocess-containing-piped-commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'command'

`command` is a shell builtin. `subprocess.Popen` does NOT run the shell by default.

To run the shell, pass `shell=True`:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output('command -v python', shell=True)
b'/usr/bin/python\n'
```

To find the full path to an executable, you could [use `shutil.which()` instead](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.which):

```
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.which('python')
'/usr/bin/python'
```

Comment: I actually tried Popen with a shell set at True but it returned 2 empty 'b' strings.. And thanks for the shutil tip, I never think of this one : now I will ! Thanks again !