# Issue using subprocess to run a PDAL bash command from Python

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, pdal

### Issue:

I cannot run a `pdal` bash command from Python using `subprocess`.

### Here is the code

based on [Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python):

```
import os, subprocess

input = '/path/to/file.ply'
output = '/path/to/statfile.json'
if not os.path.isfile(output):
    open(output, 'a').close()

bashcmd = ("pdal info --boundary "
           +input
           +" > "
           +output
           )

print("Bash command is:\n{}\n".format(bashcmd))

process = subprocess.Popen(bashcommand.split(),
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           shell=True)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    print("Output:\n{}\n".format(output))
    print("Error:\n{}\n".format(error))
```

Which gives me this output in the Python console:

```
Bash command is:
pdal info --boundary /path/to/file.ply > /path/to/statfile.json

Output:
Usage:
  pdal <options>
  pdal <command> <command options>
  --command        The PDAL command
  --debug          Sets the output level to 3 (option deprecated)
  --verbose, -v    Sets the output level (0-8)
  --drivers        List available drivers
  --help, -h       Display help text
  --list-commands  List available commands
  --version        Show program version
  --options        Show options for specified driver (or 'all')
  --log            Log filename (accepts stderr, stdout, stdlog, devnull as
      special cases)
  --logtiming      Turn on timing for log messages

The following commands are available:
  - delta
  - diff
  - fauxplugin
  - ground
  - hausdorff
  - info
  - merge
  - pcl
  - pipeline
  - random
  - smooth
  - sort
  - split
  - tindex
  - translate

See http://pdal.io/apps/ for more detail

Error:
None
```

It looks as if it had stop reading the arguments of the command after the call to '`pdal`' only, which prints this help message.

If I copy the output of the first print and paste it in a bash terminal, it works properly, giving me the output file with the desired metadata. But from Python no output file is created.

### Question:

I wonder why (e.g. is there anything wrong with the redirection or the fact that the computation itself may take ~20sec normally?), and how to execute this command from Python?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306205/file-not-found-error-when-launching-a-subprocess-containing-piped-commands) doesn't provide a clear enough answer to the present issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple errors here.

- You are using an undefined variable `bashCommand` instead of the one you defined above `bashcmd`.
- You are mixing output to a Python file handle with shell redirection.
- You are not capturing the `stderr` of the process. (I will vaguely assume you do not need the standard error anyway.)
- You should not `split()` the command if you run it with `shell=True`.

More broadly, you should probably avoid the `shell=True` and let Python take care of the redirection for you by connecting the output to the file you open; and in modern times, you really should not use `subprocess.Popen()` if you can use `subprocess.run()` or `subprocess.check_call()` or friends.

```
import subprocess

input = '/path/to/file.ply'
output = '/path/to/statfile.json'

with open(output, 'a') as handle:
    bashcmd = ['pdal', 'info', '--boundary', input]

    #print("Bash command is:\n{}\n".format(bashcmd))

    result = subprocess.run(bashcmd, stdout=handle, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    # No can do because output goes straight to the file now
    ##print("Output:\n{}\n".format(output))
    #print("Error:\n{}\n".format(result.stdout))
```