# How can I run Gaussian 16 (it's a computational chemistry software) using python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to perform calculations on a large number of files using gaussian software. It takes the name of input file & the name of the output file in which it will write the results of the calculations. One of the files is as follows:

h2plus_d2.0.in

On the terminal, the following code is executing successfully:

```
g16 /home/prathvisingh526/Documents/h2plus_d2.0.in h2plus_d2.0.out
```

However, when I am doing the same thing on python using the following code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("g16 /home/prathvisingh526/Documents/h2plus_d2.0.in h2plus_d2.0.out",shell=True)
```

I am getting the following error

```
/bin/sh: 1: g16: not found
```

Kindly help!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share what code you have written so far so that people here can help you.

Comment: I've never used this software, but that seems to relatively well documented on their [website](https://gaussian.com/interfacing/)

Comment: Maybe see [File not found error when launching a subprocess containing piped commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306205/file-not-found-error-when-launching-a-subprocess-containing-piped-commands).

Comment: Type `which g16`, use the full path to binary in your code.