# Merge 4 downloaded files into one

Tags: python

I currently have 4 files that I used the linux command `split` to break up into 50 meg files.

I'm currently trying this, but it tells me it can not find the files.

```
import requests
import tempfile
import os
import subprocess as sp

def download_files_from_github(path, model_name):
    if model_name == "u2net":
        part1 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        part2 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        part3 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        part4 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        try:
            part1_content = requests.get('https://github.com/nadermx/backgroundremover/raw/main/models/u2aa')
            part1.write(part1_content.content)
            part1.close()
            part2_content = requests.get('https://github.com/nadermx/backgroundremover/raw/main/models/u2ab')
            part2.write(part2_content.content)
            part2.close()
            part3_content = requests.get('https://github.com/nadermx/backgroundremover/raw/main/models/u2ac')
            part3.write(part3_content.content)
            part3.close()
            part4_content = requests.get('https://github.com/nadermx/backgroundremover/raw/main/models/u2ad')
            part4.write(part4_content.content)
            part4.close()
            stuff = sp.run('cat %s %s %s %s > %s' % (part1.name, part2.name, part3.name, part4.name, path))
            print(stuff)
        finally:
            os.remove(part1.name)
            os.remove(part2.name)
            os.remove(part3.name)
            os.remove(part4.name)


download_files_from_github('~/.u2net/u2net.pth', 'u2net')
```

and I get this error

```
$ python tests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 34, in <module>
    download_files_from_github('~/.u2net/u2net.pth', 'u2net')
  File "tests.py", line 25, in download_files_from_github
    stuff = sp.run('cat %s %s %s %s > %s' % (part1.name, part2.name, part3.name, part4.name, path))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 423, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cat /tmp/tmp28877_uq /tmp/tmpx2t9s9we /tmp/tmpj4g8ahhw /tmp/tmpty1x7pjv > ~/.u2net/u2net.pth': 'cat /tmp/tmp28877_uq /tmp/tmpx2t9s9we /tmp/tmpj4g8ahhw /tmp/tmpty1x7pjv > ~/.u2net/u2net.pth'
```

Comment: The whole string you are passing to `subprocess.run` is interpreted as the executable name. There is no executable with that name. The quick and dirty fix could be to use `shell=True`.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh ls prints the local directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File not found error when launching a subprocess containing piped commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306205/file-not-found-error-when-launching-a-subprocess-containing-piped-commands)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a user suggested, `subprocess` thinks you want to execute the whole command as a single thing, which fails.

A good option would be replace the `subprocess.run` string argument with a list:

```py
# pass a list directly
stuff = sp.run(["cat", part1.name, part2.name, part3.name, part4.name, ">", path])
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the problem has already been resolved, if I had to do it, I would do something like below:

```
def download_files_from_github(git_paths, out_file, model_name):
    if model_name == "u2net":
        download_status = {}
        with open(out_file, 'wb') as out:
                for git_path in git_paths:
                    response = requests.get(git_path)
                    out.write(response.content)
                    download_status[git_path] = response.status_code
        return download_status
```

Then call the program as and capture the response status_code(this is important, because you may want to discard the output file in calling program if you get 404 status_code for one of urls or you may want to raise error in the download function itself if status_code is 404)

```
status = download_files_from_github(['https://github.com/nadermx/backgroundremover/raw/main/models/u2aa',
 'https://github.com/nadermx/backgroundremover/raw/main/models/u2ab',
 'https://github.com/nadermx/backgroundremover/raw/main/models/u2acc',
 'https://github.com/nadermx/backgroundremover/raw/main/models/u2ad'],
'<your consolidated out file>', 'u2net')

print(status)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```py
stuff = sp.run('cat %s %s %s %s > %s' % (part1.name, part2.name, part3.name, part4.name, path))
```

to

```
stuff = sp.run(f'cat {part1.name} {part2.name} {part3.name} {part4.name} > {path}'.split())
```

You need to pass a list to sp.run, not a string. What I'm doing is basically creating the execution string and then split it into a list of commands and parameters.