# how can I pipe result of which command to another command in subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

HOw can I pipe in result of `which somecommand` to `outerCommand` so as to replicate result of what I will do in shell as `outercommand 'which somecommand'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - How to call bash commands with pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323859/python-how-to-call-bash-commands-with-pipe)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer no it doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the suggestions of the documentation, I would avoid using the low-level interface `Popen`, which is tricky to use correctly in the long run, and to mindlessly use `shell=True`, which might expose you to [shell injection attacks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations).

I would therefore suggest a simpler approach if that's all you need: just capture the output and use it using the new `capture_output` parameter of the new `subprocess.run()` API.

This will get what you need:

```py
completed_process = subprocess.run(['outercommand', subprocess.run(['which', 'somecommand'], capture_output=True).stdout], capture_output=True)

completed_process.check_returncode()
print(completed_process.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```