# How to use '|' with os.system?

Tags: python, os.system

I want to write the ip address of my system into a file.
If i run the following command in my terminal:

```
ifconfig eth0 grep -oE '\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b' awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5} 
NR==2{exit}' > ip_config.txt
```

It creates a file called *ip_config.txt* with the following content

```
192.168.2.10
255.255.255.0
```

Now I want to run this command from my python script using os.system().
However if I run

```
os.system("ifconfig eth0 grep -oE '\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b' awk '{print 
$1,$2,$3,$4,$5} NR==2{exit}' > ip_config.txt")
```

it will create the file but the file is empty.
It seems like os.system can't handle the pipe ('|').
Any way I can force it to use the pipe?

Comment: see this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323859/python-how-to-call-bash-commands-with-pipe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - How to call bash commands with pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323859/python-how-to-call-bash-commands-with-pipe)

Answer (score 4):

Subprocess module is your friend when it comes to running shell commands in Python because of it's flexibility and extended support. You can always refer the answer by @BarT.

But if you still insist on writing something using the os module, you can very well use the popen object. Example snippet below (regex and filters according to my machine):

**Shell:**

```
$ ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet"
    inet 10.60.4.240  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 10.60.7.255
```

**Python:**

```
>>> import os
>>> f = os.popen('ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet" | awk \'{print $2}\'')
>>> my_ip=f.read()
>>> my_ip
'10.60.4.240\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

in general you can't, what you can do is to create a Popen object with stdout=PIPE then you can use communicate().

for more information read the subprocess module, specifically the create a Popen object with stdout=PIPE.

For example:

```
first_command = subprocess.Popen( ['ifconfig eth0'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
stdout, _ = first_command.communicate()
Now stdout will hold the output from running `ifconfig eth0`.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try and avoid the pipe as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib) answer by UnknwTech

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
print(s.getsockname()[0])
s.close()
```